# crunching templates in backbone.js

Tags: html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using backbone.js and during development have many .js and .html template files (one per model).
I'm crunching all the .js to one file before I deploy the app and it works great.
How can I do this for the templates too? I've had a few ideas but they have problems:

- put all templates under invisible "div" tags in the main page. however the templates will be "executed" once the browser loads them (e.g. pictures get download w/o need)
- put the encoded templates inside javascript variables. But the encoded html will not be readable which is important for client debugging
- put the templates in an external xml file. I want to avoid xml parser though. and other non-xml format will again not be readable due to encoding.

Comment: There are a few other problems with using `<div>`s to hold your templates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11659478/479863

Answer (score 1):

ok... I couldn't find anything before, but the moment after I published the question I learned about this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="user-template">
...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for templating.

What I do is pack the templates into one javascript file (templates.js), so they are not on the DOM. The templates are compiled into js variables for production, but for development they are used as is so debugging should be simple.

I've written more about this on a [blog post](http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebars-js-like-a-pro)

Answer (score 1):

on my project i do this as follows:

Backbone has Underscore in it 
and Underscore has already a very cool minimalistic Template system.
so i write the templates in separate files and get them with jQuery

```
    $.get('html_template.tpl', function(template) {
        $(body).html(_.template(template)(template_data));
    });
```

so i let the user only download templates if really needed.

Maybe it helps.

---

Underscore Template : http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

Answer (score 0):

If you just learned about `<script type="text/template" id="">` maybe [ICanHaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/) is something that you could try next or maybe [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)